# ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 38 columns, one of them is Time.
I established a bin frame space

```
timeframe=['4-6','7-9','10-12','13-15','16-18','19-21','22-24' ]
bins = [3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24]
```

Now I cut:

```
frameddata=pd.cut(df['time'],bins,retbins=True, labels=timeframe)
```

and want to group the df for different bins:

```
groups=df.groupby(frameddata)
```

here I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe need create new column:

```
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['time'],bins,retbins=True, labels=timeframe)
groups=df.groupby('bins')
```

But is possible you get some `NaN`s in new column, because values outside of range `4-24`, so `groupby` silently remove these rows.

Comment: you cannot create a column from cut!
however thanks to your hint i found out that i have to call 
frameddata[0]
which contains the bin.

Comment: @user3194861 - why? It seems some data problem. Are data confidental?

Comment: @user3194861 Or try create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).