# For Loop With Pandas Groupby Error Message: ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, pandas-groupby

When I run the following code, I get this error message:
*ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length* Can someone please help me understand why this is the case?  I browsed through a couple other related posts but I still not understand why I'm getting this error message. 
[Grouper and axis must be same length in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884704/grouper-and-axis-must-be-same-length-in-python)

```
for (community,label,lp) in zip(communities,event_labels,landing_pages):
    lp_data_simple.loc[lp_data_simple['Event Label'].str.contains(
            label, regex=True) & lp_data_simple['Landing Page'].str.contains(
            lp, regex=True) ,].groupby([(lp_data_simple.index.year),(lp_data_simple.index.month),
                            'Event Label','Landing Page','Source / Medium','Event Action']).sum()
```

I have the following three lists:

```
communities = ['Firethorne','Glendale Lakes','Kendall Lakes','Kingdom Heights','Lago Mar','Lake Shore','Rodeo Palms',
               'Cypress Oaks','Fall Creek','Plantation Lakes','Sunset Ridge','Townsen Landing','Woodridge Forest']

event_labels = ['firethorne|Firethorne','glendale|Glendale','kendall|Kendall','kingdom|Kingdom','lago|Lago',
                'lake shore|Lake Shore','rodeo|Rodeo','cypress|Cypress','fall|Fall','plantation|Plantation',
                'sunset|Sunset','townsen|Townsen','woodridge|Woodridge']

landing_pages = ['firethorne|not set','glendale|not set','kendall-lakes|not set','kingdom-heights|not set',
                 'lago-mar|not set','lake-shore|not set','rodeo-palms|not set','cypress-oaks|not set',
                 'fall-creek|not set','plantation-lakes|not set','sunset-ridge|not set','townsen-landing|not set',
                 'woodridge-forest|not set']
```

I have a dataframe like so:

```
                            Source / Medium  \
Date                                            
2018-10-16                  (direct) / (none)   
2018-10-16  zillow/paid_network / newhomefeed   
2018-10-17                  (direct) / (none)   
2018-10-17                prospecting / email   
2018-10-17                prospecting / email   

                                                 Landing Page Event Category  \
Date                                                                           
2018-10-16                              /lp-new/sunset-ridge/            KPI   
2018-10-16  /lp/cypress-oaks/zillow/?nhf_channel=6&nhf_lis...            KPI   
2018-10-17                          /lp/woodridge-forest/nhd/            KPI   
2018-10-17  /lp/woodridge-forest/email/?cid=18101714470088...            KPI   
2018-10-17  /lp/woodridge-forest/email/?cid=18101714470088...            KPI   

                  Event Action  \
Date                             
2018-10-16       Click to Call   
2018-10-16       Click to Call   
2018-10-17  Driving Directions   
2018-10-17  Driving Directions   
2018-10-17  Driving Directions   

                                                  Event Label  Total Events  \
Date                                                                          
2018-10-16  Sunset Ridge (Website) - Click to Call (832.22...             1   
2018-10-16  Cypress Oaks (Zillow) - Click to Call (832.220...             3   
2018-10-17  Woodridge Forest (New Homes Directory) - Get D...             1   
2018-10-17  Woodridge Forest (SmartDirectory Email) - Get ...             1   
2018-10-17  Woodridge Forest (SmartDirectory Email) - Get ...             2   

            Unique Events  
Date                       
2018-10-16              1  
2018-10-16              1  
2018-10-17              1  
2018-10-17              1  
2018-10-17              1
```

My end goal is to loop through these lists & pull out the relevant data I need for each community and have it grouped similar to what is below.

```
                                               Total Events  \
Date Date Source / Medium                                Event Action                       
2018 10   (direct) / (none)                              Click to Call                  3   
                                                         Driving Directions             2   
          RDC_NAV / Banner                               Click to Call                  2   
                                                         Driving Directions             5   
          classifiedads.com / referral                   Driving Directions             1   
          google / cpc                                   Click to Call                 10   
                                                         Driving Directions            17   
          l.facebook.com / referral                      Click to Call                  1   
          m.facebook.com / referral                      Click to Call                  3   
                                                         Driving Directions             4   
          msn.com / referral                             Driving Directions             1   
          newhomesdirectory / referral                   Driving Directions             1   
          newhomesdirectory.com / referral               Click to Call                  6   
                                                         Driving Directions            10   
          newhomesource.com / referral                   Click to Call                  3   
                                                         Driving Directions             2   
          prospecting / email                            Click to Call                  1   
                                                         Driving Directions             6   
          yahoo / organic                                Driving Directions             1   
          zillow/paid_network / newhomefeed              Click to Call                  4   
                                                         Driving Directions             2   
     11   (direct) / (none)                              Click to Call                  1   
                                                         Driving Directions            12   
          Hotonhomes.com / Neighborhood Watch Email      Driving Directions             1   
          Hotonhomes.com / Right Time Response Email     Driving Directions             1   
          RDC_NAV / Banner                               Click to Call                  1   
                                                         Driving Directions             2   
          SmartTouch GEO / geotargeting                  Driving Directions             2   
          bing / organic                                 Driving Directions             1   
          google / cpc                                   Click to Call                 51
```

*Update*
I was able to complete the task with the following for loop

```
for (community,label,lp) in zip(communities,event_labels,landing_pages):
    temp_df = lp_data_simple.loc[lp_data_simple['Event Label'].str.contains(
            label, regex=True) & lp_data_simple['Landing Page'].str.contains(
            lp, regex=True) ,]
    temp_df.groupby([(temp_df.index.year),(temp_df.index.month),'Source / Medium','Event Action']).sum().to_csv(community+'.csv')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732049/valueerror-grouper-and-axis-must-be-same-length)

Comment: @KenHBS Thanks for the feedback!  That helped point me in the right direction.