# Pandas pivot table Error: Grouper and axis must be same length in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to pivot hourly indexed data into a daily indexed one with hourly values as columns.

Example data `hourlyvol`:

```
2010-01-02 03:00:00    0.193571 
2010-01-02 04:00:00    0.262009
2010-01-02 05:00:00    0.179023 
2010-01-02 06:00:00    0.132121
2010-01-02 07:00:00    0.146968
```

Desired output format (not the same values because I'm pasting from another script that works):

```
                  0         1         2         3         4         5         6   ...   17        18        19        20        21        22        23
2010-01-03       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...  NaN       NaN -0.001122 -0.001461  0.001350  0.000112  0.000562
2010-01-04  0.001123  0.000337  0.002579  0.003691  0.001895 -0.001224  0.001448  ...  0.0 -0.000221  0.001766 -0.001102 -0.000772  0.000110  0.000662
```

Current code:

```
hourlyvol=price.resample('H',label='left',closed='left').apply(vol).ffill() #works fine
pivot=pd.pivot_table(pd.DataFrame(hourlyvol,columns=["vol"]),\
    index=hourlyvol.index.date,\
    columns=hourlyvol.index.hour,\
    values="vol") # Throws error
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/aytekin/OneDrive - Groupe La Francaise/Bureau/KA/commo amine/intraday/intraday_vol.py", line 29, in <module>
    values="vol")
  File "c:\Users\aytekin\OneDrive - Groupe La Francaise\Bureau\KA\Venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 100, in pivot_table      
    grouped = data.groupby(keys, observed=observed)
  File "c:\Users\aytekin\OneDrive - Groupe La Francaise\Bureau\KA\Venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5810, in groupby
    observed=observed,
  File "c:\Users\aytekin\OneDrive - Groupe La Francaise\Bureau\KA\Venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 409, in __init__       
    mutated=self.mutated,
  File "c:\Users\aytekin\OneDrive - Groupe La Francaise\Bureau\KA\Venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 625, in get_grouper    
    if not isinstance(gpr, Grouping)
  File "c:\Users\aytekin\OneDrive - Groupe La Francaise\Bureau\KA\Venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 256, in __init__       
    self.grouper = _convert_grouper(index, grouper)
  File "c:\Users\aytekin\OneDrive - Groupe La Francaise\Bureau\KA\Venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 655, in _convert_grouper
    raise ValueError("Grouper and axis must be same length")
ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884704/grouper-and-axis-must-be-same-length-in-python?rq=1) but I'm already creating a datafarame. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732049/valueerror-grouper-and-axis-must-be-same-length) has no definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can use `set_index`:

```
(hourlyvol['vol']
    .set_index([hourlyvol.index.date, hourlyvol.index.hour])
    .unstack()
)
```

Comment: this works as an alternate but i still don't understand the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `pivot_table`

```
hourlyvol['Hour_of_day']=hourlyvol.index.hour
hourlyvol['Date']=hourlyvol.index.date
hourlyvol_pivot=hourlyvol.pivot_table(index='Date',columns='Hour_of_day')
```

Comment: This could work too but doesnt explain the error. my datasets are big (gigabytes) and i'd rather not slow the script  down further.